# XNA Break the wall programming

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna, collision, angle

I'm trying to create this game (break the wall) and I have a question : 
When the ball hits the paddle it's angle should change accordingly, but how?
Any one knows and can help me?

thank you!!

Comment: Show your work first.. People can't read your mind.

Comment: There are *so* many ways to implement this.

Comment: i'm planning the game, i didnt write much. but when i though how to do this i did'nt come up with an idea. You dont need to read my mind
just give me one.
Thank you

Comment: This is mathematics, not programming

Comment: Then can you help me mathematicly?
What should be the new angle given the old one

Comment: This whole post screams "Give me" instead of "Help me." Literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Soner wrote, it is impossible to tell without seeing some code. So this answer makes some assumptions that might or might not apply to your code. Anyway, the problem could be solved as follows:

Assume that we have the ball's direction and velocity as a vector. The paddle's normal will be a vector, too. Then you need to reflect the velocity at the normal with

```
velocity := velocity - 2 * normal * dot(normal, velocity)
```

Comment: what is the dot(,) method?

Comment: In the case of vertical or horizontal walls this can be made as simple as flipping the sign of the perpendicular velocity component.

Comment: The dot is the (euclidean) scalar product, and the condition on the normal is that dot(normal, normal)=1.

Comment: Thank you all for your help
i'll try this